# How to Evaluate $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{4k-1} $

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, catalans-constant

How can I evaluate

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{4k-1} \approx - 0.198909 $$

The Sum can be given also as

$$ \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(x+1)\sqrt[4]{(-x)^{3}}}\,\left(\,\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{-x}\right)-\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{-x}\right)\,\right) $$

Unfortunately i have not been able to evaluate either the Sum or the Integral using methods I know. Mathematica gives really weird results for the integral.

Is there a closed form for this Sum/Integral?

Thank you kindly for your help and time.

**EDIT**

For those of you that still care about the question i was able to find the following closed form. I will let the above $ sum = S $

and as such

$$ S =  C-\frac{\pi^2}{16}+\frac{\ln^2(\sqrt{2}-1)}{4}+\frac{\pi \ln (\sqrt{2}-1)}{4} $$

Where $C$ denotes Catalan's constant.

Thank you very much once again to those who provided answers!

**EDIT #2 (Proof as Requested )**

I will not show this one (too much typing) but ,

$$S= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{4k-1} = 4 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(4k+3)} \frac{1}{(4k+(4n+3))} $$

next expand the terms on the RHS into a Matrix as such :

$$
\begin{matrix} 
\color{red}{+(\frac13\times\frac13)} & -(\frac13\times\frac17)& +(\frac13\times\frac1{11})& -(\frac13\times\frac1{15}) \\
\color{blue}{-(\frac17\times\frac13)} & \color{red}{+(\frac17\times\frac17)} & -(\frac17\times\frac1{11}) & +(\frac17\times\frac1{15})\\
\color{blue}{+(\frac1{11}\times\frac13)} & \color{blue}{-(\frac1{11}\times\frac17)}&\color{red}{+(\frac1{11}\times\frac1{11})}&-(\frac1{11}\times\frac1{15})\\ 
\end{matrix}
$$

**The black terms x 4 are our desired sum**

**I then added the red and blue terms to  "complete"  the
matrix**

One can then see that the matrix (complete) may be given as

$$ \left(\frac13-\frac17+\frac1{11}...\right)\left(\frac13-\frac17+\frac1{11}...\right) $$

which is just

$$P= \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{4n+3}\right)^{2} = \left(\frac{\pi}{4 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{\ln(\sqrt{2}-1)}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)^2 $$

So

$$ P = \color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(4n-1)^2}} + \color{blue}{\text{Blue terms}} + \text{Black terms} $$

but one can see that $ \color{blue}{\text{Blue terms}} = \text{Black terms} $

Therefore :

$$ P = \frac{\pi^2}{16}-\frac{C}{2}+\frac{S}{2} $$

Solve for S to find :

$$ S =  C-\frac{\pi^2}{16}+\frac{\ln^2(\sqrt{2}-1)}{4}+\frac{\pi \ln (\sqrt{2}-1)}{4} $$

where $C$ denotes Catalan's Constant.

Comment: Congratulations and +1 ! Now, you **must** explain to us the path to solution. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici proof is up as requested (edit)

Comment: You clearly have a real talent for mathematics. I would revoke my bounty if I could. What an amazing proof... the parts that I don't understand, though, are the initial sum transformation (please show us, I'm very excited to see this!) and then the statement $P=\frac{\pi^2}{16}-\frac{C}{2}-\frac{S}{2}$. Since Blue=Black shouldn't that be $P=\frac{\pi^2}{16}+2S~~$ ?

Comment: @K.defaoite lol don't say that (thank you though) ,regardless of  results i would've given bounty solely on the work you put in! ,  i will try to show the proof later on today (i will tag you) , remember that our desired sum (black) has a 4 in front of it.

Comment: @No-oneImportant. Very nice and impressive work !

Comment: For anyone curious about the proof of the identity in Edit #2: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4780845/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is going to be a long answer.

To start, you can use the [polygamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html) of order $0$ (also known as the [digamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html)) to shorten the expressions a little bit. This is tricky though - the series definition
$$\psi^{[n]}(z)=(-1)^{n+1}n!\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(z+k)^{n+1}}$$
is only valid for $n>0$, whereas for $n=0$ one must use the derivative definition
$$\psi^{[0]}(z)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\ln(\Gamma(z))=\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$$
Because for $n=0$ the series definition doesn't converge.

Despite this however, you can "abuse" the series definition for finite sums and write
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{ak+b}=\frac{1}{a}\left(\psi^{[0]}\left(\frac{b}{a}+n+1\right)-\psi^{[0]}\left(\frac{a+b}{a}\right)\right)$$
This is difficult, but not impossible to prove. We can then write our sum as
$$\mathcal{S}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{4k-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\frac{1}{4}\left(\psi^{[0]}\left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)-\psi^{[0]}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)\right]$$
In order to calculate $\psi^{[0]}(3/4)$ we can use the two formulas
$$\psi^{[0]}(1-z)-\psi^{[0]}(z)=\pi\cot(\pi z)$$
$$\psi^{[0]}(2z)=\frac{1}{2}\psi^{[0]}(z)+\frac{1}{2}\psi^{[0]}\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\ln 2$$
And plug in $z=1/4$ to obtain a linear system
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1\\
1/2 & 1/2
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\psi ^{[ 0]}( 3/4)\\
\psi ^{[ 0]}( 1/4)
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
\pi \cot( \pi /4)\\
\psi ^{[ 0]}( 1/2) -\ln 2
\end{bmatrix}$$
If we use the well known identity $\psi^{[0]}(1/2)=-\gamma-2\ln 2$ ($\gamma$ being the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html)) we can solve the system to obtain
$$\psi^{[0]}(1/4)=-\frac{\pi}{2}-\gamma-\ln(8)$$
$$\psi^{[0]}(3/4)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\gamma-\ln(8)$$
Now,
$$\mathcal{S}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\psi^{[0]}\left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)}{n}+\frac{1}{4}\left(\gamma+\ln(8)-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$

The latter is a well known sum and is equal to $-\ln(2)$. As for the former, perhaps you can use the [asymptotic expansion of the digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Asymptotic_expansion)

$$\psi^{[0]}(z)\asymp \ln(z)-\frac{1}{2z}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{B_{2n}}{2nz^{2n}}$$

$B_k$ being the $k$th [Bernoulli number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). The first few terms are
$$\psi^{[0]}(z)\approx \ln(z)-\frac{1}{2z}-\frac{1}{12z^2}+\frac{1}{120z^4}-\frac{1}{252z^6}+\frac{1}{240z^8}+...$$

Hopefully $\psi^{[0]}(z)\approx \ln(z)-\frac{1}{2z}-\frac{1}{12z^2}$ will already give us a reasonable approximation. So now,
$$\mathcal{S}\approx \frac{1}{4}\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\ln\left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)}{n}}_{S_1}-\frac{1}{8}\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n(n+3/4)}}_{S_2}-\frac{1}{48}\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n(n+3/4)^2}}_{S_3}-\frac{\ln(2)}{4}\left(\gamma+\ln(8)-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
With some work, the second sum can be decomposed into partial fractions to obtain
$$S_2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n(n+3/4)}=4\left(\frac{4}{9}-\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\ln(2)}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\ln(1+\sqrt{2})\right)$$
Or perhaps one could use the properties of the [Lerch transcendent](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html):
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+an}=\frac{\Phi(-1,1,a+1)-\ln(2)}{a}$$
To compute the Lerch transcendent one can use an [integral identity](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.14#E1)
$$\Phi(z,s,\alpha)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}e^{-ax}}{1-ze^{-x}}\mathrm{d}x ~~~|~~~\operatorname{Re}(s),\operatorname{Re}(\alpha)>0~;~z\in\mathbb{C}~\backslash~ [1,\infty)$$
I'm not the greatest at integration, but Mathematica produces
$$\Phi\left(-1,1,\frac{7}{4}\right)=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-7x/4}}{1+e^{-x}}$$
$$=\frac{4}{3}-2(-1)^{1/4}\arctan((-1)^{1/4})+2(-1)^{1/4}\operatorname{arctanh}((-1)^{1/4})$$
Which, by using the complex definitions of [arctan](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangent.html), [arctanh](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicTangent.html) and [ln](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm), one can arrive at the form we got before.

The first sum, $S_1$, is the most bothersome. Not only does it not have any reasonable closed form representations, but it converges quite slowly. So, I'm going to use an [Euler Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration#Euler%27s_transform) to accelerate the convergence of the series. For an alternating series we can use the transform
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n a_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\Delta^n a_0}{2^{n+1}}$$
Using the [forward difference operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_difference_operator):
$$\Delta^n a_0=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k~{}_{n}\mathrm{C}_k ~a_{n-k}$$
First, an index shift:
$$S_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\ln\left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)}{n}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\ln\left(n+\frac{7}{4}\right)}{n+1}$$
Let $a_n=\ln(n+7/4)/(n+1).$ Euler's transform tells us that
$$S_1=-\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N\left[\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k~{}_n\mathrm{C}_k\frac{\ln\left(n-k+\frac{7}{4}\right)}{n-k+1}\right)\right]$$
Which converges to 5 decimal precision with only $N=11$. With $N=35$ it converges to 12 decimal precision. See my implementation on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lusrqsofii). So approximately speaking
$$S_1\approx −0.288525102601$$
Now for the third sum. According to Mathematica, it does actually have a "closed form", but it's pretty horrific. I can't be bothered to typeset it all, so I'll just post a screenshot.
[image: mathematica output]

It makes use of the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html). Anyway, the numerical value is
$$S_3\approx -0.276850451954$$
So, finally,
$$\mathcal{S}\approx \frac{−0.288525102601}{4}+\frac{0.276850451954}{48}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{4}{9}-\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\ln(2)}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{2}\ln(1+\sqrt{2})}{3}\right)-\frac{\ln(2)}{4}\left(\gamma+\ln(8)-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\approx -0.198728103723$$
You might ask yourself: **why did we do all this work?** The answer: speed of convergence. If we look at the partial sums of the original:
$$\mathcal{S}_N=\sum_{n=1}^N\left[\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{4k-1}\right]$$
It converges *very* poorly. See my implementation on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gi78epksg4). Even at $N=40$, with respect to the approximate sum that I found, the partial sums of the above jump around with a relative error of $\mathbf{15\%}$ (!) So yes, our work wasn't all pointless :)

Comment: $S_3$ can be simplified to $\frac{1}{27}\left( -24\pi\sqrt{2} + 64 - 48\ln(2) - 48\sqrt{2} \ln(\sqrt{2}-1) + 9\left( \zeta\left(2, \frac{7}{8}\right) - \zeta\left(2, \frac{11}{8}\right) \right) \right)$.

Comment: wowzers that's a +1 from me

Comment: @No-oneImportant Added a graphing feature to the Desmos links. Check it out.

Comment: I think that I (say a CAS !) found it and it is not so complicated. Cheers :-)

Comment: @K.defaoite kindly check edit , i think you will find the closed form quite pretty!

Comment: @no-one important Very nice, but do you have a proof?

Comment: @K.defaoite proof is up as an edit

Answer (score 4):

I do not believe there is a "nice" closed form to this but one way to approximate would be:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1{4k-1}>\frac 14 \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n}$$

Comment: There *is* one.

Comment: @User Show us then.

Comment: @K.defaoite All integral of form $\int Q(x) \log (a+x) \, dx$ where $Q$ is a rational function is expressible via polylogarithms, so is $-\int_0^1  \frac{ y^2  (\ln(2) -\ln(1+y^4) )dy }{1-y^4}$ due to Donald's answer and factorizing the log, which is equivalent to the series. I agree that this may not be considered as nice.

Comment: @Henry Lee Enjoy your 5,000 rep :)

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer ...

The sum can be rewritten as
\begin{eqnarray*}
- \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{(n+m-1)(4m-1)}.
\end{eqnarray*}
This can be expressed as the following double integral
\begin{eqnarray*}
-\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{ y^2 dx dy }{(1+x)(1+xy^4)}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Partial fractions do the $x$ intergration gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
-\int_0^1  \frac{ y^2  (\ln(2) -\ln(1+y^4) )dy }{1-y^4}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hopefully some of these forms might give some one else a better start point for this problem.

Something similar ... (where $K$ is the Catalan constant)
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{(2n-1)(n+m-1)}=K 
\end{eqnarray*}
would certainly give hope that there is a "nice" closed form for your sum.

Answer (score 4):

The result is not so bad. If
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{4k-1}$$ For more legibility, I shall write $S$ as
$$S=\frac {A}{96}-i\frac B 4$$ where $A$ and $B$ contain real and complex parts.
$$A=24 C-5 \pi ^2+9 \log ^2\left(3-2 \sqrt{2}\right)+(24-6 i) \pi  \log \left(3-2
   \sqrt{2}\right)$$
$$B=\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+i}{2+\sqrt{2}}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-i}{2+\sqrt{
   2}}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1+i}{-2+\sqrt{2}}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1-i}{-2+\sqrt{2}}\right)+ 
i \left(\text{Li}_2\left(i \left(-1+\sqrt{2}\right)\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(-i
   \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)\right)\right)$$

$$S=-0.19890902742911208266537143997251410413430136724348\cdots$$

It is amazing that this number is very close to
$$\frac{1}{100} \left(\psi \left(\frac{1}{15}\right)+\psi
   \left(\frac{3}{16}\right)-\psi \left(\frac{7}{10}\right)\right)$$ which is
$ -0.1989090283$

Comment: It is miraculous indeed how close they are. How on *Earth* did you manage to find this? I'm very curious.

Comment: @K.defaoite. First of all the usual inverse calculator ISC. Next, one of my former PhD students developed something amazing too. But, I agree that this one is nice. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici kindly check edit for a nice closed form !!