# Prove $\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{ak-1}=a\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{ak-1}\cdot\frac1{a(n+k)-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came across this somewhat old [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3833511/how-to-evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1nn-sum-k-1n-frac14k) where the OP provides an unproved specific case of this identity for $n\in\Bbb N$,

$$S_n = \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{ak-1} = a \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{ak-1} \cdot \frac1{a(n+k)-1}$$

> Question 1: **How do we prove this?**

I fail to see how one can rearrange the finite sum into an infinite series; it almost resembles invoking a substitution while integrating.

$$\frac1n \left(\frac13 + \frac17 + \frac1{11} + \cdots + \frac1{4n-1}\right) = \frac13\cdot\frac1{4n+3} + \frac17\cdot\frac1{4n+7} + \frac1{11}\cdot\frac1{4n+11} + \cdots$$

*Mathematica* evaluates both sums in terms of the digamma function,

$$S_n = \frac{\psi\left(n+1-\frac1a\right) - \psi\left(1-\frac1a\right)}{an}$$

The easy part is expanding into partial fractions to recover this digamma form after finding the latter form of $S_n$, since

$$\psi(n) = -\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac1k - \frac1{n+k-1}\right)$$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

---

A very similar sum appeared while I was evaluating a definite integral; I managed to show

$$I = \int_0^1 \log\left(1+x^2\right) \log \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) \, \frac{dx}x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{2k-1}$$

but did not know how to continue. The identity for $S_n$ seems like a promising lead.

> Question 2: **Can we generalize** the proof for $S_n$ and extend the identity to integer $m>1$ to rewrite
>
> $$S_{n,m} = \frac1{n^m} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{ak-1} \stackrel{?}= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{ak-1} \cdot \boxed{f(a,m,n,k)}$$

It turns out that $I = \pi G - \frac74\zeta(3)$, so I think Q2's answer is affirmative in some cases.

Comment: Well, it seems $S_n =n^{m-1} S_{n,m}$, so if we know Q1, then Q2 or $f$ is done as well.

Comment: @Macavity True. I was ultimately hoping for a different $f$ that might make evaluating the $n$-sum in $I$ easier; I was picturing each factor of $\frac1n$ contributing a factor like $\frac1{a(n+k)-\cdots}$ to the summand exactly how $\frac1n$ is absorbed in the $m=1$ case. IDK yet how to evaluate$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n \psi\left(n+\frac12\right)=\frac{\pi^2}8-\gamma\log2-2\log^22$$Might be able to use the generating function for $\psi$ but that's something for a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a\ne0$ and $m\gt n$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{ak-1}
&=\sum_{k=1}^m\frac1{ak-1}-\sum_{k=n+1}^m\frac1{ak-1}\tag{1a}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^m\frac1{ak-1}-\sum_{k=n+1}^{m+n}\frac1{ak-1}+\sum_{k=m+1}^{m+n}\frac1{ak-1}\tag{1b}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^m\frac1{ak-1}-\sum_{k=1}^m\frac1{a(k+n)-1}+\sum_{k=m+1}^{m+n}\frac1{ak-1}\tag{1c}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^m\left(\frac1{ak-1}-\frac1{a(k+n)-1}\right)
+\sum_{k=m+1}^{m+n}\frac1{ak-1}\tag{1d}\\
&=an\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(ak-1)(a(k+n)-1)}+\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=m+1}^{m+n}\frac1{ak-1}\tag{1e}\\
&=an\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(ak-1)(a(k+n)-1)}\tag{1f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ add and subtract $\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^m\frac1{ak-1}$
$\text{(1b):}$ add and subtract $\sum\limits_{k=m+1}^{m+n}\frac1{ak-1}$
$\text{(1c):}$ substitute $k\mapsto k+n$ in the middle sum
$\text{(1d):}$ combine the first two sums
$\text{(1e):}$ take the limit as $m\to\infty$
$\text{(1f):}$ evaluate the second limit

Comment: Nice stepping around the series convergence issue I had, using the limit of a finite sum. +1. Obviously works only for $a \neq 0$, else there is a $-n$ for the limit.

Comment: Yes. I had thought that $a\gt0$ was specified. I need to add that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following expression of partial fractions:

$$\frac{1}{ak-1} - \frac{1}{a(n+k) - 1 } = \frac{ (a(n+k)-1 )  - (ak-1) } {(ak-1) \times (a(n+k)-1 ) } = an \times \frac{ 1}{ak-1} \times \frac{1}{a(n+k)-1}$$

Summing up both sides from $k=1$ to infinity (Check if/when the summation is valid! EG we need $ a \neq 0$), we get (Observe that the LHS telescopes, which is why we have a finite sum.)

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{ak-1} =  an \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{ 1}{ak-1} \times \frac{1}{a(n+k)-1}.$$